# Foreign Key drop down list in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a database table of orders which is displayed in a `DataGridView` (`DataTable` filled using a `DataAdapter`). One of the columns will show the supplier and in the database this is a foreign key to the `Supplier` table (int ID and varchar Name).

In the `DataGridView` this obviously only displays as a textbox with the ID. How do I get this as a dropdown list of the `Supplier` names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use the [DataGridViewColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.aspx) and set the `DataSource` from the properties of `DataGridViewColumn` you've created.